# Why is cancellation of differnetial not allowed here?

Tags: differentiation, notation, mathematics, calculus

This is about cancelation of differentials .I am learning basics of tesnor from "Mathematical Methods " by Boas. There I encountered this epression which author says are equal. $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x'_i} =  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x'_i} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x'_i}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3} \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x'_i}$$

But if I "cancel" the differentials I get,
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'_i} =  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'_i} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'_i}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'_i} =3\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'_i} $$ 
Which is wrong if we assume that the both sides are not zero and well derivatives are well defined. 
Why is this noatation going wrong or is cancellation of differential not allowed here?
I can see that if I cancel differential before expansion I get right result but I cant see what exactly is the problem in what I have written above .

Comment: is this better suited for math stack?

Comment: This is one of the problems that occur if notation is exploited without understanding the real meaning of the objects you're working with. This trick works in one variable calculus but as you can see it fails in multivariable calculus. Think about it, when you simplify in the $RHS$ you're taking one piece of the derivative and saying it equals the all thing on the $LHS$. You might be more comfortable using other notations.

Comment: An intuitive way of understanding what's going on would be this: $x'_i$ depends on $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$, so if you *simplify the differentials in one term*, say the first, of the sum you are neglecting the dependence of $x'_i$ on $x_2$ and $x_3$.